# I keep receiving updates for a job opportunity I refused

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I received a job opportunity which I have turned down via "I am not interested" link in the first email and archived it. However I have kept receiving emails about this opportunity every 2-3 days in the past month. The email itself says this job listing is not active anymore but SO still keeps sending it.

The letter (title + first paragraph):

> Update: Message from (Tessian: TypeScript Backend Engineer) Tessian - TypeScript Backend Engineer
>
> The TypeScript Backend Engineer role sent to you by Nicole Pascoulis at Tessian has expired. While the job is no longer viewable on Stack Overflow, that does not mean the job is necessarily filled and you can still express interest in Tessian.

When I try to click the not interested link again (in any of the received update letters), I receive the following error:

> You've already responded to this job.

Have I missed something? Why I am still receiving these emails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry you've been receiving so many of these emails, especially since it's kind of a useless email in the first place. I've fixed the bug by, um, deleting the email altogether. Code which doesn't exist is guaranteed to be bug-free.